# Emoji's doesn't render color in my AngularDart project

Tags: dart, emoji, angular-dart, dart-html, dart-webui

[image]

[image]In an angular dart project I am trying to populate a welcome page with app name and emoji's, but while resulting it doesn't render the color. It's only being populated in black color. kindly help.
app_component.html

```
<div class="yns-welcome">
    <div class="yns-app-icon">{{appIcon}}</div>
    <div class="yns-main-header">{{appTitle}}</div>
    <div class="yns-sub-header">{{appSubtitle}}</div>
    <div class="yns-main-footer">{{appMainFooter}}</div>
    <div class="yns-sub-footer">{{appSubFooter}}</div>
</div>
```

app_component.css

```
:host {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.yns-welcome {
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}

.yns-app-icon {
   font-size: 125px;
}

.yns-main-header {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.yns-sub-header {
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.yns-login-btn {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.yns-main-footer {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px 0 10px;
}

.yns-sub-footer {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: How does the resulting HTML andCSS look like for the emoji icons? Can you please add a screenshot from the browser devtools from  the HTML part and the "Styles" tab?

Comment: yes of course, its pure black

Comment: I Have added the resulting image in the question

Comment: That doesn't help. I'd need to see the HTML and CSS the browsers DOM actually contains.

Comment: Kindly have a look, does image contains the needful

Comment: Have you tried `.yns-app-icon {
   font-size: 125px; color: red;
}`? What is the expected behavior anyway? What color should be rendered. There is no color in your CSS except the background color.

Comment: yes, it colors the icon with only red. I am adding a image what results color:red and what I am expecting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153936/discussion-between-tushar-rai-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: kindly have a look at the image in the question, what I am expecting

Comment: Either you copied the wrong emoji code (try copying one from https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) or some style is breaking it's display. I'd suggest you select the emoji in the browser devtools and disable the checkmark in the styles tab for every entry until you find the one that causes it to not be displayed as as you expect.

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer, thank for your support and changing the browser gave me the expected solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using `Chromium` to load the page. I have seen weird things happen in `Chromium` before. The emoji renders fine in `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `Safari` on my machine.

Let me know if this helps.

Nick

Comment: Thanks Nick, yes the problem was with the browser not with the codes.